# Dynamically remove duplicate log messages

Tags: linux, logging, libvirt

Recently we had a message fill up /var/log/libvirt/qemu/.log in a matter of minutes with a line that repeated that crashed our system due to  the root partition being filled (20+ Gigs in minutes).

"block I/O error in device 'drive-virtio-disk0': Operation not permitted (1)"

Is there a way to ensure that duplicate lines are not pushed into logs, or a way to limit that directory from filling up?  Logstash maxsize will not work for us since we run it on a daily cronjob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on which logging utility you are using (rsyslog or syslog-ng)

**Rsyslog** can remove repeated messages by adding lines like:
"last message repeated 3044 times". 
To enable this option you should add:

```
$RepeatedMsgReduction on
```

to /etc/rsyslog.conf

I don't know if such reduction is possible with **syslog-ng**.

Both syslog-ng and rsyslog can completely remove lines matching some pattern:

- **rsyslog** - take a look into this manual: http://www.rsyslog.com/discarding-unwanted-messages/
- **syslog-ng** - take a look in filters. there is some example how to do it: https://serverfault.com/questions/540038/excluding-some-messages-from-syslog-ng